# How to do pagination for API results when my results are limited?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, pagination

I am using the [food2fork target="_blank"](http://food2fork.com/about/api) API to load search results onto a page. However, I run into a problem when I try to do pagination. I can only get 30 results at a time, and I don't know how to find out the total number of search results possible either. Does anyone know how I can achieve pagination for this or if it's even possible?

I built this with angular + node, hosted on heroku, if this makes a difference.

(Right now I've got it limited so that users can search up to three pages of their desired search, but it's hardcoded into the site so it's problematic for searches that give more or less than exactly 3 pages worth of results. I could have only 'prev' and 'next' buttons, but I feel that's also limiting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the doc:

> Pages (Search Only)
>
> Any request will return a maximum of 30 results. To get the next set of results send the same request again but with page = 2
> The default if omitted is page = 1

Il you want to fetch the results ranging from 31 to 60, you need to pass `page=2` in the request. It looks like the API doesn't provide the total number of results.

I don't subscribe to @Arashsoft proposal. It actually defeats the purpose of pagination which is **not** to load the full resultset. What would be the performances if you have thousands of recipes ?

But with this simple API, you could implements [*infinite scrolling*](http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html) for instance.

Comment: I just answered the OP question. He wants to know total number of results and with that API the only solution that comes to my mind is calling the API in a loop :)

Comment: It seems like the only way to find out the total number of results is to do as @Arashoft suggests, however, like you said, that does defeat the purpose of pagination and would affect speed. I hadn't thought of infinite scrolling and that seems like a great alternative for what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get more than 30 results form the API, I suggest to call the API in a loop until you get all the data (30, 60, 90, ...). Then you can paginate it easily for your end user.